# Transparency with Python Image Library

Tags: python, transparency, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to place a PNG watermark with partial transparency on top of a Facebook profile pic (jpg) using the Python Image Library. The part that should be transparent simply comes off as white. Here's my code:

```
con = urllib2.urlopen('facebook_link_to_profile_pic')
im = Image.open(cStringIO.StringIO(con.read()))

overlayCon = urllib2.urlopen('link_to_overlay')
overlay = Image.open(cStringIO.StringIO(overlayCon.read()))

im.paste(overlay, (0, 0))

im.save('name', 'jpeg', quality=100)
```

I've tried a few different ways, but haven't gotten anything to work. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The 3rd option to `paste` is a mask (see the [docs](http://effbot.org/imagingbook/image.htm)). It accepts an RGBA image, so the simplest solution is to use your overlay image again: `im.paste(overlay, (0, 0), overlay)`.

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate it. It really was that simple... I was worrying about file formats.